# How to change the url format for documentation rendering?

Tags: go, swagger, router, gorilla, go-swagger

For the below code:

```
import (

    "github.com/go-openapi/runtime/middleware"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

m := mux.NewRouter()

// handlers for API
getRouter := m.Methods(http.MethodGet).Subrouter()
getRouter.HandleFunc("/v1/items", someHandler.ListAll)

// handler for documentation
opts := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger.yaml"}
sh := middleware.Redoc(opts, nil)

getRouter.Handle("/docs", sh)
getRouter.Handle("/swagger.yaml", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")))
```

---

`http://localhost:8080/docs` & `http://localhost:8080/swagger.yaml` renders the documentation. Api handler also works fine on uri `/v1/items`

To render documentation for  `http://localhost:8080/v1/docs` & `http://localhost:8080/v1/swagger.yaml`  below are the changes done:

```
m := mux.NewRouter()

// handlers for API
getRouter := m.Methods(http.MethodGet).PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()
getRouter.HandleFunc("/items", someHandler.ListAll)

// handler for documentation
opts := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger.yaml",BasePath: "/v1"}
sh := middleware.Redoc(opts, nil)

getRouter.Handle("/docs", sh)
getRouter.Handle("/swagger.yaml", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")))
```

but does not work. Both api handler & documentation handler fails

How to render documentation on  `http://localhost:8080/v1/docs` & `http://localhost:8080/v1/swagger.yaml`?

How to render api on   `http://localhost:8080/v1/items`? With path prefix changes

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the middleware.Redoc method and the associated template the SpecURL option is used directly and is not prefixed with the BasePath.

Adding a handler for /swagger.yaml seems to work.

```golang
type Items struct {}

type Item struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func (Items) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
    items := []Item{{"Hello"}, {"All"}}
    _ = encoder.Encode(items)
}

func main() {
    m := mux.NewRouter()

    v1routes := m.Methods(http.MethodGet).PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()

    opts := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger.yaml", BasePath: "/v1"}
    sh := middleware.Redoc(opts, nil)

    v1routes.Handle("/docs", sh)
    // Assumes that the swagger file is in the current working directory and not ./v1/swagger.yaml
    v1routes.Handle("/swagger.yaml", http.StripPrefix("/v1/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./"))))

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", m)

    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

The http.FileServer needs the path to match. So the swagger file either needs to be in a ./v1 folder or the /v1 prefix needs to be removed.

Comment: It is not working. What about `"/v1/items`? For api handler

Comment: `/v1/items` works now, but `/v1/docs` does not work

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.  You just need to:

- Remove the `/v1` prefix from the paths
- Add the `BasePath` option to the `middleware.RedocOpts`(see [source on github](https://github.com/go-openapi/runtime/blob/master/middleware/redoc.go))
- Add a `PathPrefix` method to the `getRouter` definition:

```golang
    // handlers for API
    getRouter := m.Methods(http.MethodGet).PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()

    // handler for documentation
    opts := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/swagger.yaml", BasePath: "/v1"}
    sh := middleware.Redoc(opts, nil)

    getRouter.Handle("/docs", sh)
    getRouter.Handle("/swagger.yaml", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")))
```

From the documentation:

```golang
    // BasePath for the UI path, defaults to: /
    BasePath string
    // Path combines with BasePath for the full UI path, defaults to: docs
    Path string
```

Complete example: https://play.golang.org/p/U4A60KQ0lD8

Comment: hmm, what have you tried?  Pretty sure BasePath is what you need, that's what the documentation says (updated)

Comment: if I add psthprefix and remove v1 prefix from the paths,  both api handlers and documentation handlers are not working... Query edited

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to update the SpecUrl in the code I shared earlier. The following works for me. You will need a swagger.yaml file in the current working directory.

```golang
func main() {
    m := mux.NewRouter()

    v1routes := m.Methods(http.MethodGet).PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()

    opts := middleware.RedocOpts{SpecURL: "/v1/swagger.yaml", BasePath: "/v1"}
    sh := middleware.Redoc(opts, nil)

    v1routes.Handle("/docs", sh)
    // Assumes that the swagger file is in the current working directory and not ./v1/swagger.yaml
    v1routes.Handle("/swagger.yaml", http.StripPrefix("/v1/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./"))))

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", m)

    fmt.Println(err)
}
```